# Why the imaginary part of $e^{-(a+jw)t}$ can't affect the limit as $t$ goes to infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

I am learning the Fourier Transform. For a signal,
$$
x(t) = e^{(-at)} * u(t), \; a>0
$$
we know the FT of it is
$$ 
X(jw) = \frac{1}{a + jw} 
$$
During the computation of the FS, we substitute the $t$ with infinity and $0$ to get the result of the integration:
$$
e^{-(a+jw)t}
$$
How do we know when t goes to infinity the result goes to zero?
I know if $$z = e^{-at}, \; a>0$$ $z = 0$ when $t$ goes to infinity. But the previous one has an imaginary part. Why the imaginary part can't affect the result when t goes to infinity?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome, Hao Wu!  I assume that by $ j $ you mean the imaginary unit; it might be good to explain that in the question, since in math we usually use $ i $ for this.

Anyway, $ e ^ { - ( a + j w ) t } = e ^ { - a t } \big ( \cos ( w t ) - j \sin ( w t ) \big ) $, right?  As $ t \to \infty $, both $ \cos ( w t ) $ and $ \sin ( w t ) $ remain between $ - 1 $ and $ 1 $.  So we can write $ - e ^ { - a t } \leq e ^ { - a t } \cos ( w t ) \leq e ^ { - a t } $ for the real part and $ - e ^ { - a t } \leq - e ^ { a t } \sin ( w t ) \leq e ^ { - a t } $ for the imaginary part, and since both $ - e ^ { - a t } \to 0 $ and $ e ^ { - a t } \to 0 $ as $ t \to \infty $, it follows that both $ e ^ { - a t } \cos ( w t ) \to 0 $ and $ - e ^ { - a t } \sin ( w t ) \to 0 $ as well.  Since both the real and imaginary parts of $ e ^ { - ( a + j w ) t } \to 0 $, this means that $ e ^ { - ( a + j w ) t } \to 0 $ itself.

Or more briefly:  $$ e ^ { - ( a + j w ) t } = e ^ { - a t } \big ( \cos ( w t ) - j \sin ( w t ) \big ) = e ^ { - a t } \cos ( w t ) - e ^ { - a t } \sin ( w t ) \, j \underset { t \to \infty } \longrightarrow 0 [ - 1 , 1 ] - 0 [ - 1 , 1 ] j = [ 0 , 0 ] - [ 0 , 0 ] j = 0 - 0 j = 0 \text , $$ where $ [ a , b ] $ stands for any and all numbers between $ a $ and $ b $.

Comment: Let me add a side comment on $j$ symbol: FT is a common tool in signal analysis & processing, and signals are often generated & processed by electric & electronic devices. In electric & electronic engineering $i$ is reserved for electric current, hence the need for a different symbol for the imaginary unit.

Comment: Thank you!!! I understand it.

Comment: @HaoWu :  You're welcome!  If you like the answer, then you can upvote it by hitting the up arrow next to it; and you can also hit the checkmark to accept it, which will keep it at the top if more answers come in.  (But you can also move the checkmark to a different answer if a better one comes along.  The checkmark is for your own questions, one answer each; the upvote arrow is for anybody to use on anybody's questions for as many answers as they think are good.)